# Find solution of heat equation on right plane with source

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

> Find a formula for the solution to
> $$
> \begin{cases}
> w_t−kw_{xx}=f(x,t) &\text{for } x>0,t>0\\
> w(x,0)=g(x) &\text{for } x>0\\
> w_x(0,t)=h(t) &\text{for } t>0\\
> \end{cases}$$
> **Hint**: What system does $(,)=(,)−ℎ()$ satisfy?

I know I have to use either odd or even extension to find the solution for this heat equation with source, but I don't understand how to use the Hint given in my proof.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you check the system satusfied by W?

Comment: Please use MathJax to render the math. Thanks.